# I think I have multiple postgresql servers installed, how do I identify and delete the 'extra' ones?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I seem to have a few installations of postgresql on my machine somehow. I'm not sure if this is a mistake or, if Ubuntu for some odd reason duplicates direcotories and keeps them elsewhere.

I have a postgresql directory in `/etc`

one in `/usr/lib`

and  one in `/opt`

I'm properly confused at this point.

How do I go about deleting the extra ones?.
Which ones are he extra one?
I also need to make sure that my 'pg' gem in my rails env is pointing towards the correct posgresql db server.

Any thoughts on my issue would be huge.

Comment: Please avoid using unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There can be some confusion over what people mean by an installation.

- The `/etc/postgresql/` folder is the config folder for your clusters.
- The `/var/lib/postgresql/` folder is for data.
- The program binaries for each version are in separate folders usually in `/usr/lib/postgresql/`.

I really don't know about `/opt/postgresql` as I don't have that on mine.  But `/opt` is for "optional" binaries, so it's possible that your installation is here instead of`/usr/lib/postgresql/`.

In short, I think you may just have one installation which has files in multiple locations.

If you want to look at what you have installed, this may help:

**How postgresql is structured:**

To make things a little clearer postgres is structured as follows:

- A version literally refers to which version of the postgresql
  program binaries. Each installed version may have
  a cluster installed under that version. If not then that version is
  effectively dormant as it has no data or running server associated.
- Under each version there many be a number of clusters. You can think 
  of the cluster as a running prostgres server (process). Each cluster
  has to have its own port/socket file for clients to connect to. Each
  cluster will be managed by a single version.
- Inside each cluster will be a number of databases.  When a client
  connects it selects a DB to connect to.  It can ask to change which
  DB it's connected to without opening a new session, but it can only
  ever be connected to one.

**What have you got installed?**

To find out which versions are installed you can look to `dpkg` and `apt`. You should be able to uninstall versions using `apt` and `dpkg`, but be very careful not to do this before you've checked what clusters are under each version.

To find out what clusters you have use the command `pg_lsclusters`. When I call this I get the following, you will get something different:

```
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner      Data directory                     Log file
9.1     main      5432 online <unknown>  /var/lib/postgres/data/9.1/main    /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

Pay careful attention to the "Status" column. If a cluster is not online then it's just data on disk and is doing nothing. If it is online then it is running.

**How do you merge clusters?**

You can copy the content from one cluster to another using the `pg_dumpall` command to generate a backup and use `psql` to import it to the cluster you want to keep. Its worth keeping backups of everything before you start.

**How do you remove a cluster that is no-longer used?**

- Use `pg_lsclusters` to get the details about the clusters and note the
  data directory and log file for those clusters.
- Use `pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster>
  stop` to stop the cluster.
- Remove the data folder and optionally the log file.
- Finally remove the data and config. The data folder should be `/var/lib/postgres/data/<version>/<cluster>` but check the output of `pg_lsclusters` to be sure of this. The config for the cluster: All clusters will have
  their own    config folder in
  `/etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluser>/`.

**Why did you get multiple clusters if you never asked for them?**

Usually you have to specifically request a cluster to be created to get a new one. The only exception to this is when you upgrade a cluster, it will effectively create a new one and leave the old one in place.

Comment: Thanks for the iformantion.. I'm still processing it; but its all very handy.  I ran the following command to get a list of installed packages: dpkg --get-selections and this is what I found listed for postgresql:   postgres91     install
postgresql     install
postgresql-9.1     install
postgresql-client    install
postgresql-client-9.1    install
postgresql-client-common   install
postgresql-common    install    Surely I don't need all of these packages, I feel removing them all and starting over. What do you think?

Comment: If I do a `dpkg --list | grep postgres`, I get a list showing `postgresql               
postgresql-9.1           
postgresql-client-9.1    
postgresql-client-common 
postgresql-common` ... These are all fine. `postgresql` is the main one and the others are the parts that make it up.  I've not see one called postgres91.

Comment: Ok.  I uninstalled all of my  postgres packages, including the postgre91. I also went in to my rails application and uninstalled the pg gem. The pg gem, I believed had a dependency on my having postgres installed locally. But when I ran attempted to reinstall the gem it installed itself just fine(with native extensions). Any idea how this occurred?  When I initially tried to install this gem it required me to get postgres, and I am trying to re-create that state.

Comment: I'm afraid that's outside my scope of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dpkg -S  to see which package a given directory belongs to. This would have let you see if the directories belonged to different packages.