# I have multiple PostgreSQL servers installed. How do I disable auto boot for older server?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on Oracle VirtualBox. A couple months ago, I installed PostgreSQL server version 9.1 on my machine. Just recently, I learned that PostgreSQL server 9.3 supports JSON data types, so I decided to upgrade.

I upgraded to 9.3 by following the instructions here:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
```

This installed server version 9.3 on my machine alongside version 9.1. Running pg_lsclusters after a fresh boot gives:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.1 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

I then did the following post-upgrade maintenance: I exported several tables from my 9.1 server with pg_dump and restored them to my 9.3 server. I then opened my config files for 9.1 and 9.3 at `/etc/postgresql/$VERSION/main/postgresql.conf` and swapped their port numbers so that my psql client connects to the new server by default.

My question is this. Both 9.1 and 9.3 start on boot. I would like to prevent 9.1 from auto booting, as it takes up roughly 5% of my system memory. How can I do this?

Resources consulted:

The PostgreSQL doc page on starting a server points me to the standard init.d directory. My init.d directory does contain the script `postgresql`. It looks like this script can be configured to launch only one version, but the required change is not obvious to me.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/server-start.html

The post below was very informative, but it shows how to remove a cluster, not how to disable one on startup. I would like to leave my older cluster installed, as I may want to retrieve further information from it.

[I think I have multiple postgresql servers installed, how do I identify and delete the 'extra' ones?](https://serverfault.com/questions/394257/i-think-i-have-multiple-postgresql-servers-installed-how-do-i-identify-and-dele)

I have considered writing a script to kill the server once the system has finished loading, but this seems inefficient. Is there a cleaner way to disable version 9.1 on boot?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For less of a hack, edit `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/start.conf` and replace `auto` with `manual` or `disabled`.

**Note**: Invoke `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing this file.

Comment: Thanks ch2500! This solution is intuitive and does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer like this for several hours.  THANK YOU immensely.

Answer (score 10):

Debian created several scripts (like the pg_*cluster utilities) to simplify running multiple versions or installations of PostgreSQL on a single server, which is why this isn't documented on postgresql.org.

I'm not sure if PostgreSQL's own `.deb` package uses the same startup mechanism as Debian, but looking at the package I have, if you create `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1` (even if its an empty file) then `/etc/init.d/postgresql` will assume you want to control that version separately and won't start it by default. You can still start it with

```
service postgresql start 9.1
```

to override the version search.

Comment: Thanks DerfK, this worked. I created a the file you suggested, put a hash bang in it, and made it executable. When I rebooted, pg_lsclusters gave:

`Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file`

`9.1 main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log`


`9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log`

Comment: The packages from the PostgreSQL Debian packaging team are identical to the ones from Debian. You should use the pg_*cluster infrastructure instead of hacking up your own sysv init start scripts.